# How do I add the src directory instead of the individual directory(folder) with .js files?

Tags: node.js, git, express, backend

```
-src (main folder)
  |-db
     |--database.js
  |model
     |--models.js



git add .\src\
error: 'src/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed

git add
```

i try whole src folder(directory) push in git but i got error as shown above.

and i also try to push db,model folder sepratly but get "Your branch is up to date with 'oral/main'","nothing added to commit" as a error while a type git add,git status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. `sudo rm -rf **/.git`
2. `cd ~/path/to/src` <--- go to your src folder
3. `git init`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`

**Important:**

The `sudo rm -rf **/.git` command is dangerous as it recursively deletes all `.git` directories within the current directory and its subdirectories. The reason we used that command to remove an existing Git repository. So if you have any local git history in your project. **Don't use it.**